# Is there a solution for AJP proxied websocket connections?

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxy, websocket, ajp

I'm currently using an AJP proxy through apache to tomcat 8. I don't want to reason why I'm using AJP, but the basics are that Apache site outside the firewall while tomcat is inside the firewall with multiple apps being virtual hosted through the one apache instance.

A component to the app has been added with the need for websockets. I know that our current AJP implementation will not support websockets, however I'm looking for an alternative that someone else has confirmed working, i.e. different apache module, I'm using mod_proxy_ajp.

If there is no known module to allow this to work does anyone know of any works in progress for an enhancement to any of the existing modules or a new module?

FWIW I'm using spring4 websocket support with a STOMP endpoint and SockJS.

Answer (score 4):

At the time of your question there is no solution for WebSocket support via AJP.

Apache does have mod_proxy_wstunnel but this support proxying of WebSocket using the HTTP protocol itself to the backend server.  AJP work differently.

.

See this tomcat mailing list item for some useful background:

https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/201408.mbox/%3C53FF3A3A.3040507@christopherschultz.net%3E